# Control Group inside Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, subscriber

I need to create a control group inside Marketing Cloud. A control group would be a subgroup of a data extension to whom I would not send campaign information. Example: If I had a DE with 500 campaign members, I could have 100 members as a control group and 400 as "not control group".

Then I would measure the 400 members success against the 100 members success to have an overview of campaign success. Is there any form to measure this inside SFMC?

And case have a sync between Sales and SFMC, is there a form to measure?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/186067/target-vs-control-using-automation-studio/186079#186079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not anything out-of-the-box, but you can:

1. Add a Boolean field to your DE
2. Query `TOP 10 PERCENT` for your control
3. Use an AMPscript `Lookup` in your email for the Boolean field
4. Wrap a `RaiseError` with an `IF` statement, if the lookup field returns “Control” then the `RaiserError` will skip the send.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use an Exclusion Script for this - if you use RaiseError, it will still add to the Count whereas Exclusion doesn't. You can use the same logic to check for the Boolean field in your Exclusion Script Lookup function.

Comment: More than one way to skin a cat. You can also use Journey Builder for this.